# Distinguish applications emitting events to AI using Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow

Tags: azure-application-insights, event-flow

I have two services running in Azure Service Fabric. Now, i want to capture some events from both and redirect them to the same instance of AI.

My eventFlowConfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "type": "EventSource",
            "sources": [
                {
                    "providerName": "My-Provider-Name"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "type": "ApplicationInsights",
            "instrumentationKey": "AI_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY"
        }
    ],
    "schemaVersion": "2016-08-11"
}
```

This works just fine. One problem though: in AI I cannot tell if a particular trace item came from service A or service B. So, i need a way to add some custom property to AI items coming from a particular app (service). Like, "Service A" or "Service B". Ideally, i should also be able to add PartiotionId & ReplicaOrInstanceId of that service instance, but that is a bonus without which i can live.

**UPDATE:**

As @cijothomas [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103256/7232025), we can use an ITelemetryInitializer. This works because EventFlow uses TelemetryConfiguration.Active. We can do this in the constructor of our service:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new TelemetryInitializer("Service A", context.TraceId));
```

And here is the definition for the TelemetryInitializer class:

```
class TelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly string _roleName;
    private readonly string _roleInstance;

    public TelemetryInitializer(string roleName, string roleInstance)
    {
        _roleName = roleName;
        _roleInstance = roleInstance;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = _roleName;
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = _roleInstance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same ikey is used for multiple apps, they can be distinguished using their cloudRoleInstance. If its not auto-populated, then you can write own telemetry initializer to populate it correctly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer

`item.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = "service A or B"`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear here in that this question is in the context of the EventFlow llibrary (as may be apparent from the name and structure of the config i've provided). This library seems to set "cloud_RoleInstance" to the name of the VM it's running on and i cannot see how to customize it.

Comment: After some investigation, it appears that EventFlow (indirectly) uses TelemetryConfiguration.Active, so the approach you suggest actually works. I've update my question to include the code.